# Iterate through a table for selenium testing

Tags: selenium, testing, cucumber

I want to go through a table and iterate all the rows of the table and want to check validation for a particular columns data, like which date is past date need to identify.

```
WebElement tableElement = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='tableID']/tbody/tr"));
    String rowElement = null;

    for(int i = 0; i < 9 ; i ++){
        rowElement = tableElement.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='column" + i + "']/td[3]")).getText();
        System.out.println(rowElement.toString());
    }
```

Error i got ->

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='tableID']/tbody/tr"}
```

Though I double check the table id and it is correct. I am new to selenium testing. Please help to get the data.

Comment: Your table ID may be correct, but your locator is not.  You're missing the asterisk after the double slash.  Your resulting tableElement is null.

Comment: pls elaborate me the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to find the table by using ID not xpath.

```
WebElement tableElement = webDriver.findElement(By.id("tableId"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested the code, but below is the correction I allude to in my comment to your original post:

```
WebElement tableElement = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tableID']/tbody/tr"));
    String rowElement = null;

    for(int i = 0; i < 9 ; i ++){
        rowElement = tableElement.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='column" + i + "']/td[3]")).getText();
        System.out.println(rowElement.toString());
    }
```

Although I think it would probably be best to create an array of table records:

```
List <WebElement> rows = webDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[@id='tableID']");

for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
   String rowElement = rows.get(i).findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='column" + i + "']/td[3]")).getText();
}
```

The above is also "air code" and not tested, might contain typos, take it as more psuedo code.

Comment: I called mine simply rows[] and yes, I now realize that I did not adjust my example code.  I'll fix that now.

Comment: It still may not be correct.  I can't be sure without seeing the actual HTML code in question.

Comment: bill i am new in selenium and tried to learn,It will be helpful for me. thanks

Comment: May i have ur mail id please so that i can send the code and discuss?